# Get string between special characters using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, regex-group

I am trying to get a string between the "@function" and "@" for the input string:

```
inputText = "@function square @default 2 @type Int @brief squares default number"
```

What would the regex expression be in order to get the text between '@function' and '@'?

In order for the following (in Java):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( some magic regex expression... );
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputText);
functionName = m.group;
System.out.println(functionName);
```

to print "square"

Comment: It would be `@function`, followed by zero or more letters that are not `@`. The JavaDocs for Pattern explain about character classes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

regex:

`@function(.*?)@`

This should place "square" into the first capturing group. You can then use `Matcher.group(int)` to grab that group. As in the below code:

`functionName = m.group(1);`

> group(int group)
>   Returns the input subsequence captured by the given group during the previous match operation.
>
> ***https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)***

**EDIT**

added '\s' to trim whitespace

https://regex101.com/r/PH54FV/1

Comment: I get the exception:  "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:485)" Not sure why.

Comment: The backslashes for the white-space escapes need escaped themselves. I removed them to help alleviate some confusion

Comment: Also, you need to perform a match operation as @JoopEggen pointed out

Comment: I think @yahavit has a preferable approach.  `.*` Captures are slippery critters.  Making it reluctant helps but the not @ approach is more reliable.